# Mango, IE and Anchors

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-phone-7, anchor, windows-phone-7.1

I have a demo page,

http://forum.tiedtheleader.com/html4.php#bottom
http://forum.tiedtheleader.com/html5.php#bottom

and when using IE in the Mango update, the page isn't scrolling down to the anchor for the HTML5 page.  Can anyone else confirm this behavior for me using their NoDo windows phone, or other Mango updated phones?
Thanks!

UPDATE 1:
Seems that this isn't fixed in Mango RTM.
http://twitter.com/#!/plaberge/status/101345992993017856

UPDATE 2:
It has been confirmed fixed in Mango RTM.
http://twitter.com/#!/plaberge/status/101632130475495424

Comment: in the NoDo emulator the page is displayed without the need to scroll

Comment: Works fine on a NoDo Phone (HD7)

Comment: Thanks for looking, it's strange that this behavior is happening as anchors are pretty trivial and common.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is an issue in mango that is (afaik) being fixed in rtm

**Edit**

This bug was fixed in 7720.

Comment: I've refined the issue to HTML5 support.

Comment: btw, I've got 7712 which is only a few builds away from RTM 7720, and the issue is still here.  Any insight you care to share as to why you think RTM will have a fix?

Comment: I've gotten confirmation that it will be fixed.  I've updated the OP.